# Finding periodicity of trajectory time series in python

Tags: python, time, time-series, frequency, periodicity

I am doing a time series analysis and I am trying to find the periodicity of my time-series. I have done the following code and found the graphs (see attached):

```
    # Periodicity of the two trajectories
from statsmodels import api as sm
# convert dataframe to array
np_df= np.asarray(df['Combined'], dtype=float)
# remove mean to create signal oscillating around 0
np_df= np_df- np.mean(np_df)
#get the autocorrelation coefficient
acf= sm.tsa.acf(np_df, nlags=len(np_df))

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 8))
lag = np.arange(len(np_df)) / 2. / 24.
plt.plot(lag, acf)
plt.xlim((0, 120))
plt.xlabel('Lags (days)')
plt.ylabel('Autocorrelation')
```

[image: Photo from code above]

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 8))
plt.plot(lag, acf)
plt.xlim((0, 22))
plt.xlabel('Lags (days)')
plt.ylabel('Autocorrelation')
```

[image: Graph 2 of code above]

Using fft pack to find periodicity

```
from scipy import fftpack
ft_df= fftpack.fft(np_df, axis=0)
freq= fftpack.fftfreq(np_df.shape[0], time[1]-time[0])
periods= 1/freq
plt.figure()
plt.plot(periods, abs(ft_df)*1e-3, 'o')
plt.xlim(0,22)
plt.xlabel('Period')
plt.ylabel('Power ($cdot10^3$)')
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph 3]

**My question is i think the periodicity, from what i can interpret is 1 and maybe 2.5? Am I correct in my method and interpretation?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm no pro at signal analysis, so take this with a grain of salt...

Your autocorrelation shows that 15 lags (ish) is your highly correlated.  So that would be your best estimate.  That said, either a signal is or is not periodic.  If it is periodic, I'd expect to see a 1.0 autocorrelation at some lag, not 0.85 or such.  Perhaps there is some noise or something.

I'm not quite sure what your are doing with the `fftfreq`, perhaps somebody else could lend a hand there.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I appreciate it